# Masking Many Objects With 1 Mask Using `getChildAt(i).mask` Not Working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5.5

I am attempting to apply a mask to all objects on the stage except for a couple. There are a lot of different objects, and the amount of them will change in the future, so I want the masking to be done dynamically.

I wrote this code:

```
var i;

for (i = 0; i < this.numChildren; i++) {
    if (this.getChildAt(i).name!="stage_kelp_bg" && this.getChildAt(i).name!="magnifier_mask") {
        this.getChildAt(i).mask = this.magnifier_mask;
    }
}
```

The above code is inside the document class's constructor method. Simply stating something like:

```
this.stage_kelp.mask = this.magnifier_mask;
```

works flawlessly, but only for that one object. Any idea what's wrong?

No errors are thrown, the objects just simply don't get masked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further research shows me that I cannot apply 1 mask to multiple objects. I have to have a mask for each object, or put all the objects into one container and mask that container.

Apparently you can use a layer to mask multiple objects on the timeline, but you can't do it programmatically without adding all the objects to one container. Unfortunately I can't do this without re-coding the entire application, so I will be using the timeline to mask things.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to better move all the movieclips to be masked in a single movieclip. This would be easier, if it's feasible in your case.

Answer (score 0):

How about `for each`

```
for (var mc:movieClicp in this){
                  mc.mask=mask_}
```

Comment: I get `C:\[path]\classes\ivk_kfz.as, Line 36 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type String to an unrelated type flash.display:MovieClip.
`    ---- Line 36 is `for (var mc:MovieClip in this){`

Comment: Further research shows me that I cannot apply 1 mask to multiple objects. I have to have a mask for each object, or put all the objects into one container and mask that container.